# SVN commands to create remote folders and files with content

Tags: svn, cmd, repository

I currently work on a setup script (**.cmd** file) for my application. When used, this script shall create a cmd, which creates folders and files in a remote SVN repository. The current command I use is:

> svn mkdir -m "Setup" ".$svn_root_repository."/NEW_FOLDER1"

where `$svn_root_repository` is a remote SVN repository.That command creates the new folder `NEW_FOLDER1` in the repository, no problem so far.

With that command I do a commit directly. What I really want is to create and commit multiple folders at once (also files with content). Is there a way to create them on-the-fly?

The repository I want to create the folders in is **NOT** the same as where the .cmd file (which currently contains the svn commands) lies, so I can't use `svn add`, because `svn add` adds, as far as I know, only in the same repository. Or is there something like an optional parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like `svn import` might do the trick?

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.importing.html#svn.tour.importing.import

Comment: This looks pretty good!
I will look into this and give some feedback if that works for me (most likely in the middle of next week or so)

Comment: Works great except that if you import one folder, it does not add that folder but the nested elements in that folder. Because of that after the import I've got a mess in the SVN repo

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from `svn mkdir --help`:

```
1. Each directory specified by a working copy PATH is created locally
   and scheduled for addition upon the next commit.

2. Each directory specified by a URL is created in the repository via
   an immediate commit.
```

So AFAICS your only alternative is: check out the project, create the directories locally, then commit all your changes at once.

Comment: I already read the help, but the problem is, that I want to create folders and files in another repository via a script.
If I use mkdir, I can do that, but I would have to commit each folder I create.
Also there is, AFAIK, nothing like mkfile, which would create a file...